# ASP.Net dropdown list - multiple postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback, autopostback

I have some inconsistent behaviour with a drop down list.

When it postback and the selected index is 1, it goes through and works as it should, gets the data, builds the UI, and writes everything to the screen.

if the selected index is 2 then it goes through the BuildUI() method, and then goes through the loop again thinking that the selected index is 0 and then doesn't build the UI.

this is the code

```
Protected Sub Page_Complete() Handles Me.LoadComplete

    If _IsAuth = True Then
        'if user is authorised to use the application, and the drop down menu has UK or GE 
        'selected then the the UI will be build for the user. 
        If Page.IsPostBack And ddlCharterVersion.SelectedIndex > 0 Then

            BuildUI()
            'once the UI has been built the dropdown list is to be hidden
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "ddlCharterVersion", "$('#paymentType').hide();", True)
        Else
            'if the user is not authorised they are passed a message showing that they are not authorised from the master
            'page and the panel holding the divs and information will be hidden
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "hidePayments", "$('#panelHead').hide();", True)
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub ddlCharterVersion_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlCharterVersion.SelectedIndexChanged
    ddlCharterVersion.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

And this is the dropdown on the page.

```
<div class="col-md-10 pull-left "><asp:dropdownlist runat="server" width="200px" id="ddlCharterVersion" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="-- Select Charter Version -- ">-- Select Charter Version -- </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="UK">UK</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="GE">GE</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:dropdownlist></div>
```

When debugging the application I don't hit any errors that should cause the page to postback.

what puzzles me the most is that selected index position 1 works fine, position 2 does not.

If anyone can see directly what the issue is I would be very grateful for your assistance.

--update--

[image]

-- update 2 --

when debugging this, I never hit any of the exceptions, and have a breakpoint on each of them and none of them are ever hit.

```
 Protected Sub BuildUI()
    'gets the next record for payment
    GetNextRecordForPayment()
    If noRecords = False Then
        'if there are records, concatenate the list of payments into one row in a list
        ConcatenateListOfPayments()
        ''write the records to the UI
        writeRecordsToUI()
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub GetNextRecordForPayment()
    Try

        ''if a user already has a record locked and has refreshed the page for any reason 
        ''get this record back until they pass it to the excptions queue or validate for payment

        'UserHasRecordLocked is returned as an object. Either as the contactId of the locked record or False
        Dim UserHasRecordLocked = CheckForLockedRecord()
        Dim lockedRecord As Long
        Dim contactIdParam As New SqlParameter("@LockedRecord", SqlDbType.BigInt)
        Dim charterVersionParam As New SqlParameter("@CharterVersion", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        charterVersionParam.Value = ddlCharterVersion.SelectedValue

        'check the type of object of UserHasRecordLocked
        If UserHasRecordLocked.GetType = GetType(Long) Then
            'if it has a record then assign the value of UserHasRecordLocked
            'to the sqll parameter.
            contactIdParam.Value = UserHasRecordLocked
        Else
            'else give it a default value
            contactIdParam.Value = 99999
        End If

        'place all parameters into a list object of sql parameter
        'this has been done this way so that you dont have to be 
        'precious or careful of where you place your parametss
        Dim listOfParam As New List(Of SqlParameter)

        listOfParam.Add(contactIdParam)
        listOfParam.Add(charterVersionParam)
        ''gets all records due to be paid
        Dim dt As DataTable
        'get the first payment \ contact back in a datatable. 
        'brings back all the parts of the payment, ie redress, d&i, hmrc deductions
        'and later concatenates them into one line
        dt = DataAccessLayer.FindRecords(listOfParam, _charterPayments, "dbo.usp_getFirstRecordForPayment")

        If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            noRecords = True
            'if there are no records inform the user that there are no payments to be made this day. 
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "noPayments", "$('#noPayments').modal();", True)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'build a list of payments using a payee class 
        BuildListOfPayments(dt)

        'using MoreLINQ to get the First or Default record to get the most basic of information out. 
        Dim paymentInfo = listOfPayments.FirstOrDefault()


        ''if payment is an IVA, C&R or Deceased Case this will be thrown to the exceptions for manual handling. 
        If paymentInfo.isException = True Then
            'record the exceptions
            Dim recorded = RecordNewException(paymentInfo.ContactId, paymentInfo.ContactPartId, paymentInfo.ExceptionReason, True)
            If recorded = True Then
                'post the page back to get the next record and start the loop again
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, False)
                Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
            End If
        End If

        Try
            'set the class level variable 
            _PaymentCategory = paymentInfo.Category

        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim recorded = RecordNewException(paymentInfo.ContactId, paymentInfo.ContactPartId, "Cannot match complaint against a category type", True)
            If recorded = False Then
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, False)
                Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
            End If
        End Try
        'lock the record so that no other user can be working on this at the same time 
        LockRecord(dt)

        If paymentInfo.charterVersion = "GE" Then
            'if the payment is coming from GE Charter then complete various checks
            checkGeCharterPayments(paymentInfo)

        ElseIf paymentInfo.charterVersion = "SANUK" Then
            'if the payment is coming from GE Charter then complete various checks
            checkSanCharterPayments(paymentInfo)

        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Catch sqlEx As SqlException
        PassToErrorHandler(sqlEx, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(), System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name)

    Catch ex As Exception
        PassToErrorHandler(ex, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(), System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a `ddlCharterVersion_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler but where do you register it?

Comment: in the object properties, I will add an image of it to the post

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have edited my post to show you in an image

Comment: It's probably because you set ddlCharterVersion.Enabled = False. When a control is disabled it will not post back any value. That way you can get a 0 index value of ddl. To be sure I need to look at BuildUI() function.

Comment: that's what I initially thought, however with the index being set to 1, it persists as I was needing.

Comment: @Lesmian I have added my code for this too, I get all the way through and it goes through BuildUI() and no errors are reported and then it goes through the load_complete again

Comment: @SimonPrice What about this: If paymentInfo.isException = True Then
            'record the exceptions If recorded = True Then
                'post the page back to get the next record and start the loop again
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, False)? It does not use catch, but checks for expection in other way?

Comment: its not an exception.. checked that already as we decide that in the database